# Connecting home elliptical trainer to TV power

Tags: current, diy

I'm attempting to use a TV addiction to help motivate an exercise routine. To do this, I am going to connect an elliptical trainer to the power of a television set (flatscreen). Here is my plan:

I measured the power out to the fan on the elliptical at 6.6V (the fan only runs when the elliptical is being actively used) I am hoping to replace the fan with a cable to the television connected to a relay that I'll embed in the television which will switch power from the standard power input, thus allowing the elliptical to "authenticate" power, but will not actually provide power. The power to the television will still come in through the standard 110 plug.

Assuming that the relay is rated well above 110, and assuming that it is rated for 6.6 V switching, are there additional considerations?  Should the relay run in series with the fan to provide the same load?  Is the relay the right choice?  Should I add an opto-isolator to the circuit?  What kind of load does a fan typically have compared to a relay?  Would too little load likely be a problem? I didn't measure current through the fan while it was running because it was a pain to keep the elliptical going (via walking) while measuring, but maybe I should just give it 6.6 V and measure it.

Thanks!

Comment: I expect the relay will work fine in place of the fan. I would advice however to use an optocoupler for galvanic seperation from mains. This is especially important is the trainer has things like heart rate monitoring built in and your body is or can be connected directly to the trainer's electrical system. An off the shelf 'power switch tail' might be a suitable solution. You can probably connect the tail in parallel with the fan.

Comment: It might be good to provide a delay on the relay (15 seconds or something?) so that you can stop briefly to get some water and the TV won't turn off immediately.

Comment: @RJR: A relay *is* a form of galvanic isolation. Adding an optocoupler would be complicated and redundant.

Comment: @DaveTweed you're right, provided the relay is designed for mains use and the PCB is designed with the correct safety margins.

Comment: @RJR: Obviously, the same caveats would apply to your optocoupler.

Comment: Majenko's comment is right: Have you considered the effect on your TV of (worst case scenario) putting it on, then off, then on... ? I mean, this info should be verified, but I have the feeling the TV won't like it...

Comment: The relay would be in parallel with the fan, not in series.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful about repeated connect / disconnect of the actual power of the TV. Chances are the power supply is not designed to handle that. TVs, after all are not unplugged that often.

I find it difficult to go with the proposed solution to send the remote control command. Unfortunately, most TVs have a single on/off button to toggle power, so it will be a bit more complicated to provide dedicated on and off commands to it.

I suggest an alternative: why not pass the cable signal through a relay? You don't fiddle with the TV, but no pedalling, nothing to watch. (use a SPDT relay to short the tv input while disconnecting, otherwise there might be enough coupling to actually have no effect)

Comment: Most TVs have a single on an off button but most TVs still have discreet on and discrete off codes. Any average programmable remote can send them.

Answer (score 1):

A different idea might be to use a "universal remote" programmed with your TV and then electrically actuate one of the buttons, perhaps using your relay idea above. That way, you could potentially hit different switches...for example, you could MUTE the TV instead of turning it off, or you could hit the SOURCE button, to change away from the cable signal, etc.  These ideas might be less harmful to the TV than power-switching it on and off repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your article to charge a battery pack that would provide 15 minutes of battery power to your wireless router, assuming that you are watching some thing like Netflix or other such platform. If you stop, your Internet will go down, but your TV will stay on. When you are done exercising, unplug the router from the battery pack and plug it back in to the wall

Answer (score 0):

I would throw an arduino in there to add a time delay between the elliptical stopping and the TV power shutting off. The arduino will require some power source like a wall wart.

I would also recommend using a SSR over a regular relay, as it will be easier to drive.